# .current-item Selector in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm a little confused with this css snippet:

```
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #be5b70;
}
```

If I understand correctly, the first part will select all the children anchors of the hovered list item (list item must be inside an element of class menu).

But what about the second part?

Why is there a need for both of them? I tried removing the second part and couldn't notice any difference in the end result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

comma ( , ) separates the two selectors.
The first selector .menu li:hover will select the hovered list item from the menu.
The second selector .menu .current-item will select the current highlighted menu item. This is useful in the case where, suppose, the user does not use mouse but the keyboard to navigate. In that case the user won't hover over the list item.

Comment: Oh, I see. So we use both selectors to make sure that it will have the same behaviour whether the user uses a mouse or a keyboard. Thanks :D

Comment: It would be useful to supplement your answer with a reference to documentation about using the comma to separate multiple selectors.

Comment: I didn't refer anywhere while answering.. learnt it in college :P

Answer (score 0):

Descendant selector (`>`) select only **direct** childrens.

Comment: I think he may have been asking about the comma, not the `>`>

Answer (score 0):

Spaces between two selector like `.a .b` depicts that, the right element comes under left element <s>but not a direct child of it</s>.

Greater-than `>` sign between two selector like `.a > .b` depicts that, the right element is direct child of left element. (as @kelly says)

Comma `,`  like `.a .b, .a .c` splits two or more different selector with same CSS rule.

## Update

Sorry, space depicts both direct child & in-direct child. Special thanks to **@torazaburo**.